# Solana Mobile Dev

Tags: mobile, wallet

Is there any information on when dev handsets will be available for developers? I have registered for developer access during the reservation process where a deposit was paid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No set date yet, but targeting early Q4. Saga should be ready for the public in Q1 2023.

Comment: Is there plan to have an some kind of emulator for folks to build mobile apps till then?

Comment: yep! For our SMS features, we either have simulators available now that run on any Android device or standard emulator, or they aren't explicitly tied to Saga at all. Check out our SDK at https://github.com/solana-mobile/solana-mobile-stack-sdk, or come ask in the #sdk channel on https://discord.gg/solanamobile for more details.

Comment: Looks like it's available now https://solanamobile.com/developers

Answer (score 1):

i believe the earliest would be ‘23 according to initial communications. i may be outdated and can stand to be proven wrong.